# Error in C program (for loops)

Tags: c

```
void checker(int width,int height){
    int horizontal;
    int repeat;
    int i;
    int j;
    for(j=1; j<=height; j++){
        while(horizontal<=width){
            repeat = width/10;
            if(horizontal%2){
                for(i = 1; i <=repeat; i++)
                    printf("1");
            }
            else{
                for(i = 1; i <=repeat; i++)
                    printf("0");
            }
            horizontal++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    checker(20,10);

    return 0;
}
```

So I'm creating a pattern through C. As you can tell from my code, I'm barely getting the hang of C. As I compile and test this the pattern doesn't print out in 0's and 1's, rather it only prints the \n.

I was wondering why, I might be having a brain fart.

Thank you for the time, it's very appreciated from new comers like me!

Comment: You should post what you expected to see. Its hard for people to guess what you wanted from just non-working code!

Comment: Compile your code with all warnings & debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Learn to **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: uninitialized variables could cause your issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change/add line(s):

```
int horizontal;//not guaranteed to be zero
```

to

```
int horizontal = 0;//guaranteed to be zero
```

Otherwise, this statement may never enter the brackets

```
while(horizontal<=width){ ...
```

Also (not required, but maybe nice to have) add this line just after `int j;`...

```
...
int j;

if((width < 0) || (height < 0)) return; //prevent negative input values
```

Answer (score 3):

Horizontal is not properly initialized. Right now you are using garbage value left in memory. Give horizontal a proper value before trying to use it.

Answer (score 2):

horizontal has not been initialized.  unlike some languages, C will not default a non static local variable to 0. It will be just whatever value happens to be in memory.

Comment: `C will not default a value to 0` Are you sure about that ? How about for example `global` and `static` variables which are stored in Data Segment?